# Change table color when mouse pointer is over table row

Tags: html, css

I use this code to set style of html5 table. How I can change the row color when I move mouse pointer over table row. I would like to change table color when I more mouse pointer over table row.

```
.table th,
.table td {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.new_table th,
.new_table td {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.table th {
    background-color: #eceef1;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: If you are asking if hovering over a specific child tr can change a CSS property of the parent table: it cannot. There are currently no parent selectors in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean the `:hover`?

```
.table tr:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When mouse is over table row it is also over table itself

```
table:hover{
  /* change table style */

}
table tr:hover{
  /* change table row style */

}
```

will do the trick